# Cron-like expression to match next day at a specific hour

Tags: java, linux, cron, schedule

I'm developing something in java that needs to execute at a specified date and time.

I need a way to express as a **STRING** a way to schedule something to the **next day** at 12:00pm. This is a business rule. The next day at 12pm no matter which date is today.

Examples:
(1) If now is 2021-06-**25**T**16:00** then I want to schedule it to 2021-06-**26**T**12:00**
(2) If now is 2021-06-**25**T**11:00** then I want to schedule it to 2021-06-**26**T**12:00**
(3) If now is 2021-12-**01**T**12:00** then I want to schedule it to 2021-12-**02**T**12:00**

I immediately thought using Linux ***cron*** expression to achieve this but I cannot figure it out how to express it.

Note that the expression 0 12 * * * (at 12:00pm every day) doesn't work for example (2)

**UPDATE**
I'm not forced to use *cron* so maybe there is another way to express this.

As I mentioned before: this will run in Java. My java program will read this cron-like expression and it will calculate the next date and time based on that expression.

Comment: If now is 12:00pm, should it schedule for now, or wait until tomorrow?

Comment: @jxh it should wait until tomorrow. Is a bussiness rule. It is always the next day at 12pm

Comment: If now is 12:00am, should it schedule for now + 12 hours, or for now + 36 hours?

Comment: If now is june 25 12:00am it will schedule june 26 12:00pm

Comment: If you have full control over how your program behaves, then it is unclear what is preventing you from implementing whatever behavior makes sense to your program. In any case, my posted answer will work generally: any scheduling on that day triggers a wake up at just before midnight that same day, and the real event is scheduled for noon the next day.

Comment: I do not have full control. Anybody can update that cron expression. The only thing I can do in my program is read the expression and get the next date and time of execution

Comment: You seem to imply you can change the specification language used to describe when a job is to fire. I think that would be full control.

Comment: A use case scenario as an example: I have a properties file. A plan text file with a property with a expression. Something like next-execution=0 12 * * *. My program is running (java, .net, bash, etc.) and reads it and interpret it. Boom! next execution is date 2021-06-26T12:00:00. Done. Thing is if now is 11:00am that cron expression gives me 2021-06-25T12:00:00 and not 26. As I said, I do not have full control. That property can have anything you can imagine. I can only interpret it

Comment: You are presenting a problem assuming a specific syntax. Why are you limited to that syntax? Isn't it your java program translating the specification into a date? Why are you bound to that date?

Comment: I do not. I specified in my question "I'm not forced to use cron so maybe there is another way to express this.". I thought that a cron expression was the answer because cron already solved similar problems. Maybe its not. That part of the question is answered. Is there other way to create the expression? Other tool I do not know yet?.

Comment: I already stated how I would solve it in cron. If you want to do it in some other way, you can literally choose any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with simple cron line. Crontab pattern is repeatable, so you can take out today's day but cron will skip this day every next week. For example: `0 12 * * 2/1` “At 12:00 on every day-of-week from Tuesday through Sunday.”

Your script will run only once? If so then you should probably look for bash timer that will take difference between current time and next day 12pm and then will go asleep until time is up.

If your script will run repeatedly then same approach, bash script that will sleep until the time comes and then appends `0 12 * * *` pattern to your crontab.

Comment: "Your script will run only once?" No. It should read this "cron"-like expression and should know when will be the next date and time of execution. This is not a linux specific question. I'm only interested in a standarized way to express the next day at 12pm and tought that cron could do it some way expressed it as a string.

Comment: and yes... maybe a cron expression is not the answer for what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to schedule a cron job for the day you want it to run.

```
1 0 26 6 6 reschedule-for-noon
```

Then, the `reschedule-for-noon` script could remove the above cron entry and add the one you really want at noon. Possibly by changing the `EDITOR` to be `ed` and pipe in commands to it.

For example:

```
EDITOR=ed crontab -e <<.
s;.*reschedule-for-noon;0 12 * * * thing-to-do-at-noon;
wq
.
```

Note that the script works generically. So, you could specify the rescheduling should happen just before midnight.

```
59 23 * * * reschedule-for-noon
```

---

You seem to want a `cron` syntax to indicate the periodic firing of the job should only start from the next day on. There is no such syntax.

For a one off job using `cron`, I would do it as I specified it. But, for a general purpose utility, I would probably create a script that would run at midnight every day.

```
0 0 * * * schedule-next-day-jobs-today
```

And that script would read a list of crontab entries from a special file and add them to the current crontab. So, users that didn't want jobs to start the current day would add entries to that special file. The script would then clear out the special file, so that it begins empty.

---

A little less efficient, but perhaps easier to deploy, would be a special script that doesn't do anything at all, called `NEXT-DAY`. Then. users simply prefix their command with `NEXT-DAY`, and if it got executed too early because it was later in the current day, it wouldn't do anything.

```
0 12 * * * NEXT-DAY real-command
```

Then, a separate cron job script could fire off every day at midnight, and perform find and replace of `NEXT-DAY` with an empty string on the crontab file.

This would sort of mimic a syntax for specifying something should happen the next day instead of today.

Comment: The string should be always fixed and no matter wich date and time is today is should schedule for the next day at 12pm.Im asking for cron but actually a need a way to express it as a string and cron already has a standarized way to express it as a string. This is not linux, cron or a specific language problem.

Comment: I provided a specific solution example to your specific problem example, but the solution script was "generic". I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I miss-interpreted your answer then. But still is not what I'm looking for. Maybe cron is not the answer for what I need. The probem is that my current requirement says that I need the date and time of tomorrow at 12pm, but maybe (problaby) somebody will update that expression. Maybe that somebody needs the date and time of today at 12pm. Maybe it needs to run an hour from now. Maybe every monday at 12pm. I cannot "hack" the expression

Comment: The hurdle you presented in your question was to make it schedule for the specified time the next day. Isn't that answered?

Comment: Sorry then. I'm not posting a programming challenge. I'm asking if there is way to express what I'm looking for in a cron expression or any other standarinzed expression.